# Verify that at least one of the three TextView is written

Tags: java, android, alert

hi everyone I hello everyone I have an application
with three TextView in a fragment and I want at least one of the three TextView is never empty, that is, at least one of the three extview must always be written.
My code is:

```
TextView comment_text = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addtext_comment);
TextView mymenu = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mymenu);
TextView mymenu2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mymenu2);
String comment = String.valueOf(comment_text.getText());
String mymenu_text= String.valueOf(mymenu.getText());
String mymenu2_text= String.valueOf(mymenu2.getText());
if (validate(mymenu_text) && validate(mymenu2_text) && comment.length()==0||
validate(mymenu_text) || validate(mymenu2_text)||comment.length()!=0) {
Log.d("main_activity_spinner", "it's ok");
}                    
public boolean validate(String text) {  
      if (text.contains("null")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Attenction!");
            builder.setMessage("please insert at leat comment or delat or status");
            builder.show();
            return false;
        }else
        return true;
    }
```

Now my code, if I write in one of the three textView, it returns the alert "please insert at least comment or delay or status" and then Log("it's ok"),but I want that if I don't write in any of the TextView, I get back an alert and if I write in one of the three TextView (or if I write in two or in all three TextView), I return the Log "it's ok". How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that at least one of them has text, you just have to check whether all the strings are empty. If so, show your warning, and if not, "it's ok":

```java
EditText comment_text = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.addtext_comment);
EditText mymenu = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mymenu);
EditText mymenu2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mymenu2);

String comment = comment_text.getText().toString();
String mymenu_text= mymenu.getText().toString();
String mymenu2_text= mymenu2.getText().toString();

// if all three strings are empty, show the alert, otherwise log "it's ok"
if( comment.isEmpty() && mymenu_text.isEmpty() && mymenu2_text.isEmpty() ) {
    // all of them are empty
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Attenction!");
    builder.setMessage("please insert at leat comment or delat or status");
    builder.show();
}
else {
    // at least one has text
    Log.d("main_activity_spinner", "it's ok");
}
```

*Note 1*: I assume these are actually EditText views, not pure TextView instances, since TextView is not editable by a user at runtime.

*Note 2*: For this to work, you have to call it at the time of validation. If you put this in something like `onCreate` it will be meaningless since the user wouldn't have had time to enter anything anyway.

Comment: And if you want to automate this, just do it inside a text changed listener.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to show an alert dialog from a text changed listener (annoying popup UI pattern...), but you could set an error message or something.